# Why is typescript's higher-order function not an error even if a function with a reduced number of arguments comes?

Tags: typescript

All Source: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-lslwj?file=/src/index.ts

```js
function inFunc1(a: number, b: number) {
  return a + b;
}

function inFunc2(a: number) {
  return a + 99;
}

function inFunc3() {
  return 765;
}

function wrapper(f: (arg1: number, arg2: number) => number) {
  return (a1: number, a2: number) => {
    console.log(f);
    return f(a1, a2);
  };
}

let aa = wrapper(inFunc1)(1, 2);
let bb = wrapper(inFunc2)(3, 4);
let cc = wrapper(inFunc3)(5, 6);
console.log(aa, bb, cc); // {aa: 3, bb: 102, cc: 765}
```

Each of the three functions above has 2,1,0 arguments. However, TypeScript doesn't give an error. Is it the intended design?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [TypeScript wiki FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ) is a great place to start looking for answers to common TypeScript questions. [One of these questions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) is exactly what you are asking:

> #### Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?
>
> > I wrote some code like this and expected an error:
> >
> > ```
> > function handler(arg: string) {
> >     // ....
> > }
> >
> > function doSomething(callback: (arg1: string, arg2: number) => void) {
> >     callback('hello', 42);
> > }
> >
> > // Expected error because 'doSomething' wants a callback of
> > // 2 parameters, but 'handler' only accepts 1
> > doSomething(handler);
> > ```
>
> This is the expected and desired behavior. First, refer to the "substitutability" primer at the top of the FAQ -- `handler` is a valid argument for `callback` because it can safely ignore extra parameters.
>
> Second, let's consider another case:
>
> ```
> let items = [1, 2, 3];
> items.forEach(arg => console.log(arg));
> ```
>
> This is isomorphic to the example that "wanted" an error. At runtime, `forEach` invokes the given callback with three arguments (value, index, array), but most of the time the callback only uses one or two of the arguments. This is a very common JavaScript pattern and it would be burdensome to have to explicitly declare unused parameters.

> There is currently not a way in TypeScript to indicate that a callback parameter *must* be present. Note that this sort of enforcement wouldn't ever directly fix a bug. In other words, in a hypothetical world where `forEach` callbacks were required to accept a minimum of one argument, you'd have this code:
>
> ```
> [1, 2, 3].forEach(() => console.log("just counting"));
>              //   ~~ Error, not enough arguments?
> ```
>
> which would be "fixed", but *not made any more correct*, by adding a parameter:
>
> ```
> [1, 2, 3].forEach(x => console.log("just counting"));
>                // OK, but doesn't do anything different at all
> ```

Comment: @VLAZ I left the extra gap in the quote there because I omitted some stuff about optional parameters that I thought wasn't relevant.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I didn't realise this was the case.